# Power 8 IBM i 8286-41A 6 core, install Ubuntu server

Tags: ibm

I'm planning to buy a new power 8 IBM i model 8286-41A 6 core.
I want to install Ubuntu on a partition.
Is Ubuntu compatible with that model?
Does anyone have experience?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation provided by IBM, Ubuntu is not supported on that specific model.

However, Red Hat Enterprise and SUSE are.

Source Information: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamdistros.htm

Comment: Thank for answer. In your opinion i can try anyway to install or does not run at all. I prefer ubuntu than other distro

Comment: I would say try it anyway. Just know that there may be hiccups. That's a nice machine though. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

i found this ibm doc:

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/linuxonibm/liaam/liaamvirtoptions.htm

it seems that Ubuntu 15.04, any subsequent updates is support with PowerVM Virtualization.

What do you think about?
Thanks